# WcfRestfulServices passing parameters apart from body not QueryString in Postman

Tags: c#, postman, wcf-rest

When i passing parameters through querystring in **Postman** for hitting my **Wcfrestfulservices** it's working fine.
**Client POSTMAN ::**

[http://localhost:12345/InvestUtiServices.svc/GetFoliosbyPAN?ApplicationID=jdhd@dkj&Password=ddjkk3ODkk-JhifhR7t4/k=&AppVersion=5.0&DeviceDetails=10.134.4.44&Source=website&PAN=BDXFD2F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkM9d.png)

**in Service ::**

```
public Stream GetFoliosbyPAN(string ApplicationID, string Password, string AppVersion, string DeviceDetails, string Source, string PAN)
```

But based on client requirement we shouldnot passing parameters through querystring only from body.
**Like in Postman body:**

```
http://localhost:51462/InvestUtiServices.svc/GetFoliosbyPAN
{
"ApplicationID" : "dfdfd",
"Password" : "sddf",
"AppVersion" : "5.0",
"DeviceDetails" : "10.333.3.33",
"Source" : "website",
"PAN" : "dfdddf"
}
```

But values are not passing, we get null values when hitting the service.

How can i pass values from body in POSTMAN?

Thanks in advance.[image: Parameters apart from body]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your method must be a POST method, then only it will accept post parameters.

Second, you are passing parameters as a JSON object

```
{
"ApplicationID" : "dfdfd",
"Password" : "sddf",
"AppVersion" : "5.0",
"DeviceDetails" : "10.333.3.33",
"Source" : "website",
"PAN" : "dfdddf"
}
```

So you need to change your method declaration that uses complex object containing all the parameters as properties

From

```
public Stream GetFoliosbyPAN(string ApplicationID, string Password, string AppVersion, string DeviceDetails, string Source, string PAN)
```

To

```
public Stream GetFoliosbyPAN(UserInfo info)
```

where UserInfo will be a class with your parameters as properties.